# Widths of columns do not sum up to totalwidth of the columns environment

Tags: spacing, columns, beamerposter

On a `beamerposter` I am embedding a few blocks within columns.

My issue now is that their widths do not seem to add up correctly. In particular If I have two columns 10cm wide, the whole thing will be bigger than one column of 20cm. It doesn't look as if column separators are at work anywhere.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue,fg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=20cm]
\begin{column}{20cm}\begin{block}{a}b\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=20cm]
\begin{column}{10cm}\begin{block}{a}b\end{block}\end{column}
\begin{column}{10cm}\begin{block}{a}b\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am almost certain this is a duplicate of some sort, but just cant seem to find a useful "original"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `columns` does not include any side margins for the text, while `block` does. But they have the same width text width. By including some lines (long lines 20 cm and short 10 cm) the spacing between the (text) columns of 10 cm becomes more clear.

[image]

One solution would be to decrease the width of the 10 cm columns by 8pt as in the next picture. The 8pt I got from the overfull hbox in the log. Since the width of the column is decreased the 10 cm lines are a bit misleading since they are longer than the text.

[image]

The code for the second picture is (remove the `-8pt` to get the first).

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[scale=1]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue,fg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
  \tikz[|-|] \draw(0,0)--+(20cm,0);
  \begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=20cm]
    \begin{column}{20cm}
      \tikz[|-|] \draw(0,0)--+(20cm,0);
     \begin{block}{a}
        \tikz[|-|] \draw(0,0)--+(20cm,0);
     \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=20cm]
    \begin{column}{10cm-8pt}
     \begin{block}{A}
        \tikz[|-|] \draw(0,0)--+(10cm,0);
        \lipsum[2]
     \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{10cm-8pt}
     \begin{block}{B}
        \tikz[|-|] \draw(0,0)--+(10cm,0);
        \lipsum[3]
     \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a bunch! Is there a way though to do this dynamically? I.e. without using the magical constant of 8pt, with actual lentgth (I assume that is itnernatlly defined somehow. Or even better, is it possible to restrict the left and right padding of the titles to 0pt?

Comment: I am sure there is a margin set somewhere within the beamer specifications, but I have not been able to find it. An alternative is to define your own block and then you will be able to set the margin. However, if you set it to 0pt there will not be any margins between the columns and it will be hard to read.

Comment: Sure, I'd have to ensure the spacing somehow in the end. I was just hoping to use this in order to ensure flushness in a poster design I'm working on